# Specific economy per server

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to change this code so that on multiple servers one user does not have data from another server.

Now every user on different servers has the same amount of money and the top users table is the same.

I want that a user can not earn separately on different servers.

This is my code for economy:

```
@client.command()
async def portfel(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    user = ctx.author
    users = await get_bank_data()

    wallet_amt=users[str(user.id)]["portfel"]
    bank_amt=users[str(user.id)]["bank"]

    em=discord.Embed(color=0xFFFF00)
    em.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    em.add_field(name="Portfel:", value=wallet_amt)
    em.add_field(name="Bank:",value=bank_amt)
    await ctx.send(embed=em)


@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 120, commands.BucketType.user)
async def work(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)

    users = await get_bank_data()

    user = ctx.author

    earnings=random.randrange(101)

    variable=[
        f"Posprzątałeś dom sąsiada! Sąsiad ci daje {earnings}",
        f"Znalazłeś {earnings} pieniędzy na ulicy!",
        f"Pracowałeś dodatkowo na wakacjach w Żabce, lecz twoje hot-dogi często były nie dobre, więc otrzymujesz {earnings}",
        f"Pracowałeś na polu pomagając rolnikom. Otrzymujesz {earnings}",
        f"Rozdawałeś dodatkowo na ulicy gazety dla pobliskiego kiosku. Zarobiłeś {earnings}",
        f"Poszedłeś na konkurs fotografii i wygrałeś {earnings}",
        f"Skosiłeś trawnik. Otrzymujesz {earnings}",
        f"Pomogłeś starszym sąsiadom z internetem. Dali ci za to {earnings}"]

    em=discord.Embed(description="{}".format(random.choice(variable)), color=0x33FF66)
    em.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed=em)

    users[str(user.id)]["portfel"] += earnings

    with open("mainbank.json","w") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)


@work.error
async def work_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        em=discord.Embed(description='Poczekaj **%.2fs** zanim znów użyjesz tej komendy!' % error.retry_after, color=0xFF0000)
        em.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        await ctx.send(embed=em)


@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 240, commands.BucketType.user)
async def crime(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)

    users = await get_bank_data()

    user = ctx.author

    earnings=random.randrange(300)

    variable=[
        "slabo",
        "dobrze",
        "dobrze"]

    if random.choice(variable)=="slabo":

        variable=[
            f"Próbowałeś coś ukraść ale cię przyłapano! Tracisz {earnings}",
            f"Zbierałeś ekipę na skok na bank ale twoi towarzysze cię zdradzili. Tracisz {earnings}",
            f"Próbowałeś oscamować kogoś w internecie, lecz ci się nie udało. Tracisz {earnings}",
            f"Zrobiłeś napad na pobliski sklep, lecz okazało się że w środku była Policja i cię aresztowała. Tracisz {earnings}",]

        em=discord.Embed(description="{}".format(random.choice(variable)), color=0xFF3333)
        em.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        await ctx.send(embed=em)


        users[str(user.id)]["portfel"] -= earnings

        with open("mainbank.json","w") as f:
            json.dump(users,f)

    else:

        variable=[
            f"Okradłeś sklep, zyskujesz {earnings}",
            f"Napadłeś na kogoś i ten ktoś dał ci {earnings}"]

        em=discord.Embed(description="{}".format(random.choice(variable)), color=0x33FF66)
        em.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        await ctx.send(embed=em)

        users[str(user.id)]["portfel"] += earnings

        with open("mainbank.json","w") as f:
            json.dump(users,f)


@crime.error
async def crime_error(ctx,error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        em = discord.Embed(description='Poczekaj **%.2fs** zanim znów użyjesz tej komendy!' % error.retry_after,
                           color=0xFF0000)
        em.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        await ctx.send(embed=em)


@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 1250, commands.BucketType.user)
async def slut(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)

    users = await get_bank_data()

    user = ctx.author

    earnings = random.randrange(500)

    variable = [
        "slabo",
        "dobrze"]

    if random.choice(variable) == "slabo":

        variable = [
            f"Przebrałeś się za dziewczynę żeby kusić chłopaków, lecz ci się nie udało i cię okradli! Tracisz {earnings}",
            f"Zrobiłeś to tamto, ale klient oraz pracodawca nie był zadowolony! Tracisz {earnings}",
            f"Twój przyjaciel cię zaprosił do klubu tanecznego, lecz okazało się że to oszustwo i jak byłeś pijany, okradli cię! Tracisz {earnings}",
            f"Śledziłeś swoje znajome, lecz te cię przyłapały i pobiły! Tracisz {earnings}"]

        em = discord.Embed(description="{}".format(random.choice(variable)), color=0xFF3333)
        em.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        await ctx.send(embed=em)

        users[str(user.id)]["portfel"] -= earnings

        with open("mainbank.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(users, f)


    else:
        earnings = random.randrange(5000)
        variable = [
            f"Zrobiłeś to tamto, i klient ci dał {earnings}!",
            f"Przebrałeś się za dziewczynę żeby kusić chłopaków, a ci zapłacili tobie {earnings} żebyś się odczepił!",
            f"Twój znajomy ci polecił klub taneczny i się okazało że to był dobry pomysł. Wszystkim się spodobał twój taniec. Zyskujesz {earnings}"]

        em = discord.Embed(description="{}".format(random.choice(variable)), color=0x33FF66)
        em.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        await ctx.send(embed=em)

        users[str(user.id)]["portfel"] += earnings

        with open("mainbank.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(users, f)


@slut.error
async def slut_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        em = discord.Embed(description='Poczekaj **%.2fs** zanim znów użyjesz tej komendy!' % error.retry_after,
                           color=0xFF0000)
        em.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        await ctx.send(embed=em)


@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def addmoney(ctx, user:discord.User, *,count):
    await open_account(ctx.author)

    users = await get_bank_data()

    user = user
    users[str(user.id)]["portfel"] += count
    em=discord.Embed(description=f"Dodano {count}zł {member.mention}", color=0xFFFF00)
    em.set_footer(text=f"Komenda wywołana przez {ctx.message.author.name}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed=em)

    with open("mainbank.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)

async def open_account(user):
    users = await get_bank_data()

    if str(user.id) in users:
        return False
    else:

        users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]["portfel"] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 0

    with open("mainbank.json","w") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)
    return True


async def get_bank_data():
    with open("mainbank.json","r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    return users


@client.command(aliases = ["lb"])
async def top(ctx,x = 1):
    users = await get_bank_data()
    leader_board = {}
    total = []
    for user in users:
        name = int(user)
        total_amount = users[user]["portfel"] + users[user]["bank"]
        leader_board[total_amount] = name
        total.append(total_amount)

    total = sorted(total,reverse=True)

    em = discord.Embed(title = f"Top najbogatszych użytkowników!" , description = "Tabela najbogatszych osób:",color = 0xFFFF00)
    index = 2
    for amt in total:
        id_ = leader_board[amt]
        member = client.get_user(id_)
        name = member.name
        em.add_field(name = f"{index}. **{name}**" , value = f"{amt}",  inline = False)
        em.set_footer(text="Komenda wywoałana przez {}".format(ctx.message.author.name), icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        if index == x:
            break
        else:
            index += 1

    await ctx.send(embed = em)
```

Python 3.8.4
Discord.py-latest version

Comment: Maybe you could try to replace all occurences of `user.id` (specifically `str(user.id)`) with `str(ctx.guild.id) + "/" + str(user.id)`? This would make all keys of items of your dict specific to guilds (which is what servers are called in discord.py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a nested dictionary so that each guild has its own dictionary of users then access it like so:

```py
bank[guild][user]
```

Lets create a function to update a users balance:

```py
async def update_balance(member, amount):
    server = member.guild

    with open("mainbank.json","w") as f:
        bank = json.load(f)

    if server not in bank:
        bank[server] = {}

    if member in not bank[server]:
        bank[server][member] = 0

    bank[server][member] += amount

    with open("mainbank.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(bank, f)
```

Then whenever you want to update a user's balance, you can call this function.
Be wary though, you need to give a `discord.Member` object and not a `discord.User` object.